# Should I delete my question as unclear?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

With a later thought I realized [my question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86461/48011) may not fit the standards for this site. Should I delete it? It seems half-way from *unclear* to *primarily opinion-based*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say yes. I'd say that the question is too broad. Plus it involves non-technical comments about price and strange comparison with L series (a prime objective may be still better than zoom even if zoom costs thousands).

P.S. This is information readily available in variety of web sites in digestable form along with sample photos.